Apache Drill VALIDATION ERROR: Expected columns count differs from the returned one
I am trying to query a table in oracle database using apache-drill.
The query is :
SELECT * FROM <storage_plugin>.<schema>.<table> LIMIT 10;

and getting this error.
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: VALIDATION ERROR: Expected columns count differs from the returned one.
Expected columns: []
Returned columns count: 156

The same query works for other tables in database, and also using Oracle SQL developer the query is being executed correctly.
I also tried to do DESCRIBE on the table, but getting empty result.
What might be wrong here ?

The query cannot work when used directly in an Oracle database because the LIMIT keyword is not valid syntax.

I ran the query in Apache drill.
